# How to host a REST web api in a .NET core 5 console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, webapi

I'm having trouble getting my .NET Core 5 console app to host a web Api. My guess is that I might be going about it the wrong way, but I can't find any solutions to this on google that's specific to .NET Core console apps. So, I'm at a loss.

Currently, I've been trying to use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost package to so that I don't have reliance on IIS or any other container. This is important. It has to be a console app. Anyway, I've followed all the examples and it fails to work.

**MY SYMPTOMS:**

It runs and the Startup code executes successfully, but when I use a client to make a request to the Api, it just sits and spins forever. It connects to the port, but that's it.

**MY CODE:**

First, my Startup class:

```
public class StartupApi
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration( IAppBuilder appBuilder )
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi( config );
    }
}
```

Now my Program code:

```
class Program
{
    //private static readonly Startup _startup = new Startup();

    static int Main( string[] args )
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:80/";

        using (WebApp.Start<StartupApi>(url: baseAddress))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Api Started");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now my controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById( int id )
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        
        return product;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        return products.Where( p => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

I've used both a web browser and Postman to test the requests, but nothing.

Is it possible that this package isn't fully compatible with .NET Core? Is it possible that there's a better solution for .NET Core? All of the articles I've read focus on .NET Framework for this.

Comment: Could there be a problem with "Console.ReadLine"? It might be waiting for input indefinitely. I don't know if it is correct usage or not, I just don't remember seeing it used in that way.

Comment: That was taken from an example on the web. The WebApp only runs while within the using block. Leave the using and the web api shuts down. So, that's okay. In fact I did start off using Thread.Sleep to have it sleep indefinitely. The same thing happened.

Comment: What's crazy is this is exactly like the various examples on the web. I didn't deviate at all. But every one of those examples never said it was .NET Core, so that makes me wonder.

Comment: On another note, Convention based routing is so web api 1 these days. The recommended routing scheme for newer versions is [Attribute based routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) I am not sure but Convention based routing might even be obsolete for .Net5

Comment: I'm wondering if that's the heart of the problem. the client gets to the api, but the endpoint never gets called. Maybe .NET Core is not handling the Convention based routing.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem!

The Nuget package I was using was apparently mainly for .NET Framework, and I was unable to get it to work with .NET Core 5.

Instead, I used Kestrel, as that doesn't have any IIS or container requirements.